# Entity Framework SqlQuery returing anonymous type records

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I am writing a reporting system which is flexible. As a part of it I create SQl statements by concatenating like

sql=" select * from a_v where ename=1 "

I want to know How I can use

```
db.Database.SqlQuery(sql)
```

to return collection of anonymous records so it is truly flexible.

I can't find a way to do it as it seems to be strongly typed.

Can it be made to return anonymous type records . An example would be great

Comment: I'm not absolutely sure about what I'm going to say, but an OR/M maps types while an anonymous type can be whatever. Maybe you can map actual types and map them to anonymous types using Automapper or something like this

Answer (score 0):

I may have interpreted your goal incorrectly, but it sounds to me that you want to use projections. You can return lists of anonymous types from Linq. An example would be:

```
var anonymousListOfBoxes =
   from b in CustomerBoxes
   select new {
        b.Customer,
        b.BoxID,
        b.Barcode
   };
```

now, anonymousListOfBoxes will be a System.Linq.IQueryable<(anonymous)>. Each item will have 3 properties - Customer, BoxID and Barcode. The list will not be a collection of CustomerBoxes as it would be if you did not use a projection with "select".